# Why is running `EXEC AS USER='xyz'` yielding "Unspecified error occurred on SQL Server."

Tags: .net, sql-server, oledb, adodb, excel-2013

I am finishing up the conversion of an EXCEL VBA application to an EXCEL Document-level .NET customization, and am getting the error

> Unspecified error occurred on SQL Server. Connection may have been
>   terminated by the server.

with HRESULT=0x80004005 and COMPlusExceptionCode = 0xE0434352 running this SQL statement:

```
EXEC AS USER='domain\userID'
```

This construct is used to vet various test accounts, and all the appropriate permissions are set on the SQL Server side.

- The code runs fine from within the old VBA environment.
- Connection string in both environments is identical:
  "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=ABC;Data Source=DEF;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=QRST;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;"
- The same connection string works fine for other SQL statements; just the EXEC AS USER='XYZ' fails (for all acceptable values of XYZ).
- ADODB 2.7 is being used in both cases
- The exception being thrown is of type `COMException` with no InnerException
- The Exception Source is "Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQl Server".

Does anyone have thoughts on why this error would be occurring? Is there perhaps a Trust issue involved from using Click-Once deployment from a intranet network location? I have run out of ideas for tracking this issue down.